# More efficient collapsable list targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to use jquery's slideDown/slideUp/slideToggle functions to animate these collapsable elements when I click on them. Here's a snippet of the html layout of the elements:

```
<ul> 
                    <li class="category1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <div class="tag1">
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                            </div>

                        </ul>
                    <li class="category2"><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <div class="tag2">
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                            </div>  
                        </ul>
                    <li class="category3"><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <div class="tag3">
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                                <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
                            </div>  
                        </ul>

</ul>
```

Here's the javascript code that I've tried. It works, but it is very long. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing.

```
$('.category1').click(function(){
    $('.tag1').slideToggle('200');
    $('.tag2').slideUp('200');
    $('.tag3').slideUp('200');
        return false;
});

$('.category2').click(function(){
    $('.tag1').slideUp('200');
    $('.tag2').slideToggle('200');
    $('.tag3').slideUp('200');
        return false;
});

$('.category3').click(function(){
    $('.tag1').slideUp('200');
    $('.tag2').slideUp('200');
    $('.tag3').slideToggle('200');
        return false;
});
```

Comment: You could write one click function and toggle based on the class name... but your code isn't _that_ long either.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a lot longer than what you see.. basically, there are more tags and more categories than shown. I shortened it for the purposes of posting this question.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [standard accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default).  Is there a reason the jquery accordion wouldn't work?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You're closing your list items before you make the new sublist a child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am pretty sure your markup is invalid as only `li` elements should be nested in `ul` elements (someone correct me if I am wrong).  I changed the markup to this:

```
<ul class="outer"> 
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="cat1"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat1"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat1"><a href="#">derp</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat2"><a href="#">derp</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="cat3"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat3"><a href="#">derp</a></li>
            <li class="cat4"><a href="#">derp</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is the script:

```
$(".outer > li > a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".outer ul").slideUp();   
    var next = $(this).next();
    if(next.is(":visible")) { return; }         
    next.slideDown();
});​
```

[And here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uSBTv/4/).

As you can see, I simply slide up *all* the `ul` sections and then slide down the next one after the anchor which has been clicked.

Comment: The already open element still doesn't seem to close on click.

Comment: Ha.. oops sorry.  Some accordions function that way.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I also just noticed something else though - when I click on the inner list items, it collapses the whole element.

Comment: Oops.. Fixed.  Notice that I changed the selector from `.outer li a` to `.outer > li > a`.  This makes sure that only the first level of `a` tags cause the content to show..

Comment: Is there a variation of this that doesn't use any <a href> tags? I tried to modify the code but it failed completely.

Comment: What is the problem?  You might need to add a parameter to the `click` callback as `event` and then inside the click callback use `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your list a little bit, you want to keep the children `<ul>` within the parent `<li>`

```
$('li[class^=category]').click(function(){
  var cls = $(this).attr('class');
  cls = cls.split('y');
  cls = cls[1];
  $('.tag'+cls).slideToggle('200');          
  $('div[class^=tag]').not("div[class=tag"+cls+"]").slideUp('200');
  return false;
});
```